# Grails using spring security annotations and UrlMapping to secure controllers

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to secure a controller:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class FooBarController {

}
```

I have the controller mapped in UrlMappings:

```
"/foo/bar"
```

It seems that when I try and access the controller as `/foo/bar` the annotations are effectively ignored.

I saw something that said I need to use the `controllerAnnotations.staticRules`. My first question is:

1. Do I need to duplicate all my rules in the static rules or is it enough to say it's secured and the filters will pick up the specific rules from the annotations?

I have another scenario where I secure a contoller with UrlMappings, the default URL path is  changed but not the controller name e.g.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
MyApiController {

}
```

UrlMapping is: `/api/company/1/myApi`

In this case the annotation is picked up without any necessary configuration in the staticRules so I'm pretty confused by what needs to be configured where and under what circumstances.

Comment: I don't believe you can/should mix and match the different ways to secure controllers/actions. This could be why you are experiencing these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that the UrlMapping doesn't match the default controller mapping convention.  i.e. the Config.groovy mapping is referring to the UrlMapping instead of referring to the actual controller name.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737980/57357  for a fuller explanation.

IMO this is non-intuitive, but that's the way it currently works.  Note that it does **not** work this way if you use the InterceptUrlMap style of configuration.  If you use the InterceptorUrlMap style, you **do** refer to the UrlMappings.groovy's URL mappings.