# Grails spring-security static rules for rest resource seems not working properly

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, url-mapping

I have an Grails (2.0.4) application using Spring Security plugin (version 1.2.7.3) and the secured annotation approach (the default one, more [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html)).

Now, I have these URLs in UrlMapping.groovy with the resource key or the controller/action pair, like this:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

// other rules, all working properly

"/api/item/$id?"(resource: 'itemRest')
'/api/item/batch-delete'(controller: 'itemRest', action: 'batchDelete')
```

The RESTful mapping works perfectly with ItemRestController: every method (show, update, save, delete) is correctly mapped with the proper HTTP method. And the extra method (batchDelete) works as well.

I secured the API url, doing this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
     // ...
     '/something/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
     '/api/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

Now, I get redirected to the login page if I call:

```
http://host/context/something/bla_bla
```

But not if I call (with the proper payload, when required):

```
http://host/context/api/item/batchDelete
http://host/context/api/item/1
http://host/context/api/item
```

My suspect is that the static rules are not working properly when mapping the rest controller with the resource key.

Please also note that the "something" url is not present in the UrlMapping.groovy file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to use

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
     '/itemrest/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
      //this will be redundant after the above rule I guess
     '/api/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

Urls which are not mapped in urlMapping has to refer the `controller` directly in the rules. Have a look at the [**warning**](https://grails.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations) under `controllerAnnotations.staticRules` in the docs.

> When mapping URLs for controllers that are mapped in
> UrlMappings.groovy, you need to secure the un-url-mapped URLs. For
> example if you have a FooBarController that you map to
> /foo/bar/$action, you must register that in
> controllerAnnotations.staticRules as /foobar/**. This is different
> than the mapping you would use for the other two approaches and is
> necessary because controllerAnnotations.staticRules entries are
> treated as if they were annotations on the corresponding controller.