# spring security core secure custom url

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, config, roles

I am using `grails 2.3.9` and `spring-security-core:2.0-RC3` and using `staticRules` for security.

I have following security configurations in `Config` file:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.mkb.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.mkb.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.mkb.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSwitchUserFilter = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.errorPage = null
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/': ['permitAll'],
    '/index': ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico': ['permitAll'],

    '/controllerC/**': ['ROLE_USER'],

    '/**': ['permitAll']
]
```

there security configurations works fine.

Now I have following `URL mappings`

```
"/test/controllerA/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"(controller: 'controllerA')
"/test/controllerB/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"(controller: 'controllerB')
```

and I required to set the security for the URLs that have `/test/`, ie., URLs `myDomain.com/test/controllerA/**` and `myDomain.com/test/controllerB/**` are accessible to users that have `ROLE_ABC` role.

I have tried with

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/': ['permitAll'],
    '/index': ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**': ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico': ['permitAll'],

    '/test/**': ['ROLE_ABC'],

    '/**': ['permitAll']        
]
```

but this did not work, any user can access the controllers.

**How I define the security?**

**NOTE:-** I cannot use `@Secured` annotations. I need securities in `Config` only

Comment: Hi user1690588, did you try grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap" ? (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#configGroovyMap)

Comment: @Abincepto: I am not using `InterceptUrlMap` and if I use `InterceptUrlMap` along with `staticRules` this then getting "The website has redirect loop" in my browser, no screen is rendered.

Comment: Did you add the next line in your config.groovy ? grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap" Could you edit you post with all rules ?

Comment: @Abincepto All my security rules are already posted in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote rules, instead of staticRules. There could be an intersection with the staticRules.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you exactly want. The code I have pasted in my question is the only code that spring security added, rest of the code is auto-generated.

Comment: I think you don't have only one rule in staticRules[], because you wrote '...','/test/**',['ROLE_ABC'],'...'. Do you think there could be another rule(s) which causes this issue ? I want to check this kind of mistake.

Comment: @Abincepto I have added my full staticRules. Please have a look.

Comment: Could you try without this rule (remove the line): '/**': ['permitAll']' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60916/discussion-between-abincepto-and-user1690588).

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to explicitly specify the controllers in static rules as below:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    ...

    '/controllerA/**': ['ROLE_ABC'],
    '/controllerB/**': ['ROLE_ABC'],

    ....
]
```

I think this is exactly how you already have for `controllerC` as

```
'/controllerC/**': ['ROLE_USER'],
```

Refer [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737980/2051952). As the [doc suggests](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#securedAnnotations), this is also applicable for controller from plugins where `@Secured` cannot be used if source code is unreachable.

Comment: `controllerAnnotations.staticRules entries are treated as if they were annotations on the corresponding controller`. Yes, your answer helps, THANKS. And sorry for being so late, lots of tickets flying around. :-)

Comment: `interceptUrlMap` is capable to handle such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code if any user can access the controllers.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    ...
    '/test/**': ['permitAll'],
    ...
]
```

And for particular user you can use Spring security annotations

Add the below line before the class name.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ABC'])
```

you need to import

```
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
```

Comment: I cannot use `permitAll` because only user with role `ROLE_ABC` can access the URL. I need securities in `Config` only. No annotation.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you can use Filters in Grails : http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters
An example :

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
       loginCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
           before = {
              if (!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                  redirect(action: 'login')
                  return false
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```